# What should the OAuth2 redirect_uri be for a desktop (non-web) application?

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, harvest

I'm writing an application that will integrate a web application (i.e. Harvest).  The web application supports authorization via `OAuth2`.

The workflow seems to be:

1. Direct the user to a specific URL where they can be authenticated and give permission to my application.
2. Within that first request, I'm supposed to provide a *callback uri* that will receive the authorization token.
3. Use the sent authorization token to make requests on behalf of the user.

The first part seems simple enough, but what should the *callback uri* be?  This isn't a website, it doesn't have an exposed web interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OAuth 2.0 for desktop and mobile applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753969/oauth-2-0-for-desktop-and-mobile-applications)

Comment: Though alternatively your application can listen on localhost, according to [Google's dev guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)

Comment: @metatoaster Yeah, that other question didn't really have an answer, just a link to a 6-year old proposal to fix OAuth so that it actually worked with native apps, along with a handful of workarounds that all seem to require running a web server somewhere.  I was hoping something had changed in the last 6 years.

Comment: If by `redirect_uri` you mean `callback_uri`, it's optional as per [RFC 6749 section 4.1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.1), with [section 9](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-9) fully discuss what you need to do for your native application, which the dev guide I linked earlier also discussed. You have to do the work to figure out which of those solutions are best for you.

Comment: Also, the accepted answer in the duplicate I suggested also explicitly stated "registering a custom URI with the desktop operating system" which is also from the RFC (which stated "redirection URI with a scheme registered with the operating system").  That is basically as good as an answer you will get for these generic protocol type questions.

Comment: I used  the callback_uri to send the AuthCode then start my App  as commandline params so you can catsh communicate with your remote server.
I used https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial. if you want to know how to start your app I will send you the method